# Iterate through GridView Row with Labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Working with a GridView in C# (ASP.NET) and I'm trying to iterate over a single row. Normally it wouldn't be too difficult if I could extract the text in each cell:

```
string text = SecGrpGridView.Rows[0].Cells[i].Text;
```

However, some of the fields in my row contain Labels and I believe the only way to extract the value is using FindControl() and casting it to a Label:

```
Label myLabel = (Label)SecGrpGridView.Rows[0].Cells[i].FindControl("Label5");
string text = myLabel.Text;
```

As you can see, the second example I needed to know the ID of my label so it makes it difficult to iterate over unless I have sequentially named labels. I know that a future need will be to add more columns to my row so I'm looking for a way to iterate over this row without having to name the labels sequentially. (ie 'Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3') Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: You could of course also give real names to the labels. A potential maintenance coder will thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gather all the Labels in GridView by using the following code

```cs
public static List<Label> FindLabelRecursive(Control root)
{
    List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
    if (root is Label)
    {
        labels.Add(root as Label);
        return labels;
    }

    foreach(Control c in root.Controls)
    {
        if (c is Label)
        {
            labels.Add(c);
        }
        else
        {
            List<Label> childLabels = FindLabelRecursive(c);
            labels.AddRange(childLabels);
        }
    }

    return labels;
}
```

Then do you processing based on the labels returned.

Comment: I was getting some invalid arguments adding the root to the labels list, so I changed labels to an ArrayList. Good news is, it works! Thank you!

Comment: Grr, my syntax labels.Add(root) causes error.  I have fixed it and changed it to labels.Add(root as Label) should do well.  Your ArrayList approach should work too.